# How to change a defined value to a unspecified value by css?

Tags: css

I use an external CSS Stylesheet that I can't or don't want to change. It defines the default length of an select field.

So in the **external stylesheet** there is something like:

```
select { width: 200px }
```

Now I have some places where I want this to be different. I want the browser to choose the necessary size to accommodate the content. In **my stylesheet** I want to something like this:

```
select.some-class { width: none_specified }
```

So a select with "some-class" will not be 200px wide, but as wide as the browser thinks is right.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried just using `auto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All CSS properties have a default value. For `width` it's `auto`.

```
select.some-class { width: auto; }
```

Note that you can't always override CSS so easily, sometimes you need to use style attribute

```
<div style="width: auto;"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set it to auto.

```
select.some-class { width: auto !important; }
```

Note that I use `!important` to specify that this rule should override any other.